# react one method change two state one by one the result is not I expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started to learn to React. Doing some simple things to practice. Now I am trying to use hooks.
I created a couple of them and sims that they can not change rendering simultaneously I have a table of goods and want to click at check all and output the total price of all goods or if it was checked zero. But when I click it changes the value of the checkbox but doesn`t change the total price another time it changes the total price but doesn't change the checkbox...

```
const ProductsListDemo = () => {

    const [total, setTotal] = useState(1720);

    const [checkedGoods, setCheckedGoods] = useState([
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
    ]);

    function checkAll(e) {
        let isChecked = (total == 0)? true: false;
        e.target.value = isChecked;

        const arr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < checkedGoods.length; i++) {
            arr.push(isChecked);
        }

        setCheckedGoods(arr);

        changeTotal();
    }

    function changeTotal(){

        let sum = 0;

        for(let i = 0; i < goods.length; i++) {
            let total = goods[i].price * goods[i].amount;
            sum += (checkedGoods[i])? total: 0;
        }

        setTotal(sum);
    }
```

How could change I it to get this work? I know that another person would make it completely different but this case is vary interesting that`s why I desided to ask about it here...

Comment: Looks like you have some flaw in your logic. Why don't you post the entire React component, and not just the component functions.

Comment: Because this website wrote that I`m trying to post to much code((

Comment: When you working with forms and React, and using Functional components and hooks, I recommend you take a look at the 'React Hook Forms` library and handle your forms with it.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about `setState` is that it's asynchronous, meaning that your data isn't updated immediately. For this react has `useEffect`, which can run some logic whenever some dependency changes. In this case your dependency is `checkedGoods`. To run `changeTotal` whenever `changedGoods` gets changed, you could do something like:

```
const ProductsListDemo = () => {

    const [total, setTotal] = useState(1720);

    const [checkedGoods, setCheckedGoods] = useState([
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
    ]);

    function checkAll(e) {
        let isChecked = (total == 0)? true: false;
        e.target.value = isChecked;

        const arr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < checkedGoods.length; i++) {
            arr.push(isChecked);
        }

        setCheckedGoods(arr);
    }

    function changeTotal(){
        let sum = 0;

        for(let i = 0; i < goods.length; i++) {
            let total = goods[i].price * goods[i].amount;
            sum += (checkedGoods[i])? total: 0;
        }

        setTotal(sum);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        changeTotal();
    }, [checkedGoods]);
```